# jQuery and 'select' tag

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors

I have a `<select>` tag and I need to select the value of the selected option.

```
<select id="foo">
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

With jQuery I try to use the `val()` method to do it like this:

```
$('#foo').val();
```

The problem is that it always returns `1` - the default value of the selected option!

Why is that so?

Comment: Is it at all possible you have another element with ID "foo"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#foo option:selected").val();
```

edit: [DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/54DmJ/5/)

Comment: I think that I need to use `live()`. How to use it when I have `$('#foo').val()`?

Comment: @daGervis. you must use $("#foo option:selected").val(); or $("#foo :selected").val(); istead of $('#foo').val() to get selected value

Comment: @daGrevis The use of `live()` in that demo is completely unnecessary. You can simply use the `click` handler. See my update http://jsfiddle.net/54DmJ/7/

Answer (score 2):

When a `<select>` element contains no options with the `selected` attribute, it defaults to selecting the first option.

If you change the selection and run `val()`, you will get a different value.

Try this and tell me if it still gives you the same value every time it changes

```
$('#foo').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: That's the problem! It selects always the first option even when other option is selected by the user.

Comment: @daGrevis I can't duplicate it. I've updated my answer with something for you to try.

Comment: It returned `select` tag with all options and correct `value` attributes. Does it somehow help?

Comment: @daGrevis Wha? It shouldn't "return" anything. Have the console open and observe the output as you choose different select options

Comment: Working as expected here too. Sounds like OP is having a PEBKAC issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $('#foo :selected').val();
```

Check this:

```
$('#foo').change(function() {
    console.log($('#foo :selected').val());
}).change(); // this change will fire for first time and give the value `1`
```

Comment: It gives me the same result. Only 1st option whenever.

Comment: This is unnecessary and is even documented in the [API](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select option:selected").each(function () {
    $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen if you have more than one DOM element with the id attribute you are using in your selector.

jQuery will bind events correctly to all of the elements, but then use only the first one in DOM when requesting its value.